# useState does not re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('')

  const searchHandler = async (searchTextInput) => {
    console.log('search is:::', searchTextInput)
    setSearchText(() => searchTextInput)
  }

  const searchOnSubmitHandler = async () => {
    await loadShopsCount()
    await loadShops()
  }

  const searchClearHandler = async () => {
    setSearchText(() => "")
    console.log('onClear-----------search is:::', searchText)
    await loadShopsCount()
  }
```

On calling `searchClearHandler` after searching for something, `searchText` returns the previous state value instead of empty string. Hence, my component is not able to re-render.

How can I set `searchText` to empty string and re-render the component on calling `searchClearHandler`?

Comment: Whatever is calling `searchClearHandler` is waiting for it to complete before the next render is triggered. Calling `setVar` from a `useState` call won't actually change the value of `var` in the current render cycle, it changes the next value of `var`.

Comment: Sidenote: `searchHandler` doesn't need to be async, and your setState methods don't need to use a callback: `setSearchText(searchTextInput)` and `setSearchText('')`.

Answer (score -1):

Use useEffect.

```
useEffect(() => {
    Here your function which you want to call.
  }, [searchText]);
```

Comment: I have a SearchBar component with onChangeText props. If I set searchText as a dependency in useEffect, it will keep rerendering the component on each character input, which defeats the purpose of having onSubmitEditing (which I want).

Comment: What is about to use useCallback ??